# Jquery Dialog modal Unload Page

Tags: jquery, ajax, modal-dialog

I am using Jquery Dialog modal as a holder for new aspx page, the problem is that first time i open the page its fine, but after that the page inside the dialog will not hit page load event again, so how can i fully unload the page when the dialog close ?

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#divTest').dialog({
        modal: true,
        open: function () {
            if ($(this).is(':empty')) {
                $(this).load('WebForm1.aspx');

            }
        },
        close: function (type, data) { debugger; (window.location = 'WebForm2.aspx') },
        height: 500,
        width: 500,
        title: 'Title'
    });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: by `fully unload the page` you mean unloading the content which is been loaded from `WebForm1.aspx`? if so just remove the condition `if ($(this).is(':empty')) ` so that it will always load when its opened

Comment: The problem is Page_Load event been triggered 1st time i open the dialog, if i close and reopen the page_load will not trigger in WebForm1.aspx (the page inside the dialog),, i tried to remove if ($(this).is(':empty')) but this ddn't work

Comment: `$(this).load('WebForm1.aspx');` this is what you mean by page load event?

Comment: No, i mean server side Page_Load Event handler

Answer (score 0):

Thanks anyway Cerlin Boss, I found the solution, i had to stop browser caching for the page inside the dialog.